# sklearn select N best using classifier

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

pretty simple question here but just can't seem to find the answer in the normally great documentation for sklearn.

I am working with binary classifiers, but we can just assume i am using `LogisticRegression`, and I was wondering if there is a general way to have the classifier select, say only 10 best (most sure) data points?

For example, say I train a set with 500K data points, and my test set has 10K lines, and out of the 10K, I just want to choose 10 that have the highest chance of being true positives.  Does this make sense?

I have read about, and have been playing with the `class_weights` attribute, which works well for giving more/less weight to each of the binary outcome classes, but its not quite working for what I want in that it always give different number of position predictions, and I can't really tell how sure the classifier is about each one of those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class_weight` is used in the process of model-training to train(=fit) a better model (let us call it `clf`).

Your question is is about choosing the most sure predictions.
You just need to predict the probability (for binary classification this will be the probability of positive class)

```
y_test_predicted_probability = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

and then choose 10 points with the highest `y_test_predicted_probability`

```
#some code to do this
top_picks_indexes = y_test_predicted_probability[:,1].argsort()[-10:] # chose top 10 probabilities for class = 1

# create a vector, Y_top_picks, with all zeros except ones for the selected top probabilities
Y_top_picks = np.zeros(len(X_test))
Y_top_picks[top_picks_indexes] = 1
```

Comment: Yes thank you, after asking I looked harder at each of the methods of the classifiers and came across the `predict_proba` and `predict_log_proba` methods.  I was thinking that is what I was looking for, I will try it out.